# How to handle strings in headers using requests Python

Tags: python, json, string, rest, python-requests

I have *REST API* for which I'm trying to fetch data. The *API* is working perfectly if I use value in string format, but the *API* request doesn't work if a placeholder is used instead of value with string data type or concatenated string as in example below:

```
import requests
import pandas as pd
import time
from datetime import date
url = 'http://abc.io/api/v1/modules/get-sale-manager'

payload = {'brand_id': 'sdfghjkl', 'from_timestamp': '1119405211','to_timestamp': '111940511'} #here value's are used

params=payload
headers = {'access_token': 'xxxxxxxxx','secret_key':'xxxxxxx'}
response = requests.get(url, headers=headers,params=payload)
response.json()
```

Instead I want to use placeholder and supply calculated values as following:

```
payload = {'brand_id': str(brand_id), 'from_timestamp': str(from_timestamp),'to_timestamp':'to_timestamp'} #here value's are used
```

And I would like this also:

```
payload = {'brand_id': "'"+brand_id+"'", 'from_timestamp': "'"+from_timestamp+"'",'to_timestamp': "'"+timestamp_too+"'"}
```

But none of these two methods work. I get `500` status code, but I'm sure there's no error at server as when the values are supplied directly.

Comment: Can you clear your question. What is not working exactly? And what is your requirement?

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is in your datetime serialization. You should convert datetime to timestamp like below

```
from_time_str = str(int(time.mktime(from_timestamp.timetuple())))
to_time_str = str(int(time.mktime(to_timestamp.timetuple())))
payload = {
    'brand_id': str(brand_id),
    'from_timestamp': from_time_str,
    'to_timestamp': from_time_str
}
response = requests.get(url, headers=headers,params=payload)
```